# Java: reverse a String in o (1) space and o (n) time

Tags: java, string, reverse

Saw this question in an interview repository. Is there a way for it to be done?

My guess is, it is a trick question. There is no way to do it in constant space , as strings are immutable.

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: Is it an actual `String` object, or a "string?" A character array or StringBuilder could be considered to be a string.

Comment: can you verify whether it's an actual String object or list / array of characters?

Comment: Was the question actually asking about Java?

Comment: If you would that `String`s are immutable, it is not possible. Since you will need to allocate a second `String` to make this happen, which conflicts with `O(1)` space. However, you can use reflection to manipulate a `String`, effectively making the class non-immutable. Would never recommend this though, there are too many things going on with `String` internally that could break.

Comment: @MikeP : It is a String object

Comment: @Arjit : It is a String object

Comment: @cricket_007 : It wasn't mentioned as such. 
I am guessing the same question would  be a trivial question in C or C++. 
Hence wanted to know about Java

Comment: This is obviously an algorithmic question, not a trick question about how compilers work in Java! Besides, most of the times when a string is mentioned in an interview question you should consider a char array not an actual String object.

Answer (score 1):

What about using reflection?
like:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
public class StringReverseTest {
    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException {
        Class<String> s = String.class;
        Field m = s.getDeclaredField("value");
        m.setAccessible(true);
        String a = "1234567890";
        char[] cs = (char[]) m.get(a);
        for (int i = 0; i < cs.length / 2; i++) {
            char t = cs[i];
            cs[i] = cs[cs.length - 1 - i];
            cs[cs.length - 1 - i] = t;
        }
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

it will output 0987654321.
But only works for interview, must be avoid in any product code.

Comment: Interesting, but would never recommend any of this. The side-effects could be too dangerous. Especially stuff like hashing and internal caching could break.

Answer (score 1):

Reversing a Java `String` is much harder than it might be thought. First, many programmers consider a `String` to be an array of characters, with each character a `char`. But, despite its name, a `char` is not the same as a "character". Java strings use UTF-16 encoding, so some "characters" (in Unicode jargon, "code points") are encoded with 2 `char`s. Worse still, some of those "characters" are actually *modifiers*: the character modifies the next character (typically, to add an accent). Those pairs characters must be treated as a unit, rather than being reversed individually.

Finally, you might ask *why* reverse a string? This is an artificial problem. Nobody ever needs text reversal in an application program, because reversing some useful, meaningful, text produces useless gibberish.